# System.Text.Json is throwing TypeInitializationError

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to make a Revit 2021 add-in in .Net Framework 4.8 and I get this exception when trying to deserialize a JSON.

The code is rather simple. First, I read the text from a `.json` file, then I call the method `Deserialize()` and on that same line, the exception occurs.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\CDMModel.json");

JsonObject model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(json);
```

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Revit2021Json.dll but was not handled in user code
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer' threw an exception.

The inner exception is:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.MemoryExtensions' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1

What could be the cause of this?

P.S. Because of privacy matters, I am not able to share the json and the object, therefore I am not expecting a fully working answer. However, it would be great if we could discuss this at a purely theoretical level, if possible.

Comment: Try to look at the InnerException property of the thrown exception. It may tell you more.

Comment: System.Text.Json is not supported in .NET Framework, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netframework-4.8) for the link to the supposed documentation which states that. Plus, `JsonObject` does not exist in the System.Text.Json namespace, there is one in just System.Json but [that also doesn't support .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.json.jsonobject?view=netframework-4.8). So what are you actually using?

Comment: @VeljaRadenkovic [System.TypeInitializationException] = {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.MemoryExtensions' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, Publ...

Comment: @MindSwipe I am trying to find alternatives to Newtonsoft.Json. I have some deserialization issues with version 12 while also running Revit. So instead of going back to version 11, I was wondering if I could find some alternative JSON (de)serializers - hence, I found System.Text.JSON. Given it is not supported in .NET Framework, could you suggest any tools like this for my purpose, please?

Comment: Ah, so this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I don't know of any other library for JSON serialisation/ deserialisation for .NET, but IMO if Newtonsoft.Json is throwing errors, you should fix your code

Comment: `JsonObject` equivalent in Newtonsoft.Json is `JObject`. You can use `JObject.Parse`

Comment: @MindSwipe yeah, well, it's not actually throwing errors. It's just the fact that Revit loads newtonsoft version 9 by default and that might cause some conflicts with the version that I am using. That's why I am actually trying to find alternatives to newtonsoft so I can avoid conflicts with Revit's versions of it :D